# DropzoneJS - progressBar not waiting end of process

Tags: python, flask, dropzone.js

I'm currently building a little upload forms into my Python Flask web app. I use dropzone.js to have their powerful drag and drop file handler.

So after upload the file will be process by some Python function, and the processing time could be long. And the progress bar of Dropzone.js pass from 0 to 100 in a fraction of second, even if the background process isn't finish.

How could I have a real progress bar ?

Here is my piece of JS code :

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    url: "/upload",
    method:'POST',
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 3,
    maxFiles: 3,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    acceptedFiles: 'application/pdf',
    dictRemoveFile: 'Annuler l\'upload',
    dictDefaultMessage: 'Selectionnez un document ou glissez le',
    dictInvalidFileType: 'Ce type de format n\'est pas pris en compte',
    init: function() {
        let dzClosure = this; // Makes sure that 'this' is understood inside the functions below.

        // for Dropzone to process the queue (instead of default form behavior):
        document.getElementById("submit-all").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            dzClosure.processQueue();
        });
        this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
            let topPx = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i <= files.length; i++) {

                if (i > 0) { topPx = 80 * i }

                $("<div style='top: " + topPx + "px;' class='flash' onclick=\"$('.flash').fadeOut()\">Fichier(s) uploadé(s) avec succès : " + files[i]['name'] + "</div>").insertAfter($('.content'));
            }
        });
        this.on("error", function(file, response) {
            $("<div class='flash' onclick='$('.flash').fadeOut()'>Erreur lors de l'upload des fichiers : " + response + "</div>").insertAfter($('.content'));
        });
    }
};
```

And here is a little piece of code of the Python :

```
@bp.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for file in request.files:
            f = request.files[file]
            f.save(os.path.join(current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], secure_filename(f.filename)))
            worker_from_python.main({
                'path'  : current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                'config': current_app.config['CONFIG_FILE']
            })
            os.remove(os.path.join(current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] + secure_filename(f.filename)))
        return redirect('/upload')
    return render_template('pdf/upload.html')
```

This is the `worker_from_python.main` call that take processing time

Thanks in advance